# Overlap images issue in Swift CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I’m trying put some images on CollectionViewCell.
On storyboard, I have a collection view in a view controller.

I also set dequeueReusableCell identifier as "cell" like this. And registered it on viewDidLoad of view controller.
[identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJFpO.png)

The problem is when I add more than 3~4 images, Suddenly images in cells mess up like this.

[simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGEEt.png)

In my guess, it’s because of I added subview over and over again so It seems image views keep stacked up. I don’t know how to fix it.

I tried to initializing a view on content view of Cell, but it didn’t work.
I also read a solution about add custom cell class and .xib file and initializing cell with prepareForReuse(). But it was hard to understand and I failed to implement it.

Here is my 'View Controller' code
(*I resized UIImage to fit on Cell. It keep shows as a cropped images. I applied some ContentMode setting but it did not work at all. So I decided to resize of UIImage.)

```
import Foundation
import Tabman

class SecondTabViewController: TabmanViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

//MARK: - CollectionView
extension SecondTabViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource,
                                   UICollectionViewDelegate,
                                   UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        
        if let count = ad?.collectedImages.count {
            print("cell count = \(count)")
            return count
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? UICollectionViewCell {
            if let imageInfo = ad?.collectedImages[indexPath.row] {
                // resizing an Image
                let imageSize = imageInfo.imageData.size
                let cellSize = CGSize(width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
                let newSize = resizing(imageSize: imageSize, frameSize: cellSize)
                
                let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
                imageInfo.imageData.draw(in: rect)
                let resizingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                
                var initView: UIView?
                if let newCgsize = resizingImage?.size {
                    initView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
                } else { print("resizing error.")}
                
                
                let appendingView = UIView(frame: CGRect.init())
                let appendingImageView = UIImageView(image: resizingImage)
                appendingView.addSubview(appendingImageView)
                
                if let safeInitView = initView {
                    cell.contentView.addSubview(safeInitView)
                }
                cell.contentView.addSubview(appendingView)
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
            }
            return cell
        }
        else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        
        let width = collectionView.frame.width
        let height = collectionView.frame.height
        let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2
        let widthPadding = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
        let itemsPerColumn: CGFloat = 3
        let heightPadding = sectionInsets.top * (itemsPerColumn + 1)
        let cellWidth = (width - widthPadding) / itemsPerRow
        let cellHeight = (height - heightPadding) / itemsPerColumn
        
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
    }
}

extension SecondTabViewController {
    func resizing (imageSize: CGSize, frameSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var newSize = CGSize()
        
        let widthRatio = imageSize.width / frameSize.width
        let heightRatio = imageSize.height / frameSize.height
        var ratio: Double
        if  heightRatio > widthRatio {
            ratio = heightRatio
        } else {
            ratio = widthRatio
        }
        
        newSize.height = imageSize.height / ratio
        newSize.width = imageSize.width / ratio
        
        return newSize
    }
}
```

===============

**Update** (Xav Mac)

Unfortunately I got an error.
These are What I tried:

- Create CustomCollectionViewCell class and .xib file from new Files-Cocoa Touch Class
- In CustomCellectionViewCell.xib, I added Image View and set auto-layout to fit custom cell. And Added prepareForReuse() on CustomCollectionViewCell.swift

  - Here is CustomCollectionViewCell.swift code:

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        cellImageView = nil
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

- Registered the custom cell in viewDidLoad()  `collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell”)`
- delete reusable view cell on Storyboard. (I thought I don't need it because I registered cell from .xib already)
- I edited cellForItemAt func like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell {
        if let imageInfo = ad?.collectedImages[indexPath.row] {
            
            cell.cellImageView.image = imageInfo.imageData
            cell.cellImageView.contentMode = UIImageView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        }
        return cell
    }
    else {
        return CustomCollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

The error What I got is:
**/**:75: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
2023-06-27 18:51:47.361942+0900 **[**] **/**:75: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that when the collectionView reuse the cell It will add a new subView in the cell (stacked images effect).

So I see 2 solutions for you here, the good and the bad way.

**Good way:**

- Create a custom UICollectionViewCell (e.g: CustomCollectionViewCell)
- Add a UIImageView with constraints top/left/right/bottom according the view (put the aspect ratio to AspectFit to fit the image in the UIImageView

So after you can do:

```
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell {
         cell.imageView.image = //your image
}
```

PS: Don't forget to put imageView.image to nil in the "prepareForReuse" of the cell, to avoid image glitches.

**Bad way:**

Just before you add your new subView in the cell, you clean the cell hierarchy of the previous subView.
So you will have something like that

```
cell.contentView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

Hope It will help you !

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try it right now. I'm going to try as Good way. but I have a question. Do I need make new custom cell class file(.swift) and .xib file together?

Comment: Xav Mac! I tried but unfortunately I got an error. I added about it at Question!

Comment: No need for .xib, if you have already a Storyboard. Just create your CustomCollectionViewCell.swift file with your class in it and after in the cell of your collectionView in the Storyboard choose your CustomCollectionViewCell, after that just bind your ImageView of your cell in the CustomCollectionViewCell class (IBOutlet).

Comment: PS: the Fatal error you got, it's maybe a zombie IBOutlet in your Storyboard, delete an element in a Storyboard don't delete the binding, so you will have a crash if the binding is not removed also.

Comment: There are two zombie IBOutlet so I deleted that. But I still have same have on same code. 
Here are what I tried to fix the error:
I guessed it because I set the ImageView IBOutlet as nil on prepareForUse()
So I fix my code like this then error was gone but No image came out on CollectionView. :'(
`cell.cellImageView = UIImageView()
cell.cellImageView.image = imageInfo.imageData`

Comment: @Xac Mac It works!! 
I read some Apple Document and realized that I don't have to initialize cell.cellImageView `cell.cellImageView = UIImageView()`
I created custom cell class and .xib. and edit my code like this: `collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")`.
Instead of `register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`, I used `register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")`

Comment: I guess register() func that before I used didn't work. It seems didn’t connect custom class and collection view correctly. Still don't know why latter one is work. Can you guess why the latter method solved it? It's weird because in Apple Document of Collection View says I can register my custom cell by register(:forCellWithReuseIdentifier).